# Difference between indecisive and volatile

Tags: meaning-in-context, synonyms

I am confused about when to use indecisive and when to use volatile.

For example

He was very _________. His friends acknowledged his vacillation.

What would be the appropriate answer here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re indecisive, you have a hard time making decisions. When you finally do make a decision, you may not be confident about it, or you might change your mind. [vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/indecisive)

Watch out when a situation becomes volatile — it is likely to change for the worse suddenly. You fight and then make up with your partner often if you two have a volatile relationship.[vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/volatile)

the right answer is indecisive as the verb to vacillate means "unable to decide" [vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/vacillate)

Comment: Great I could use the source for future reference!!

Comment: People are said to be volatile when they are given to abrupt mood swings, such as sudden flare-ups of anger or sudden fits of depression.

Comment: So if it were some synonym of oscillate in place of vacillate then I presume volatile would be correct.